# Dependencies between variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

this is my first post here and I need a help. I'm preparing a matrix of all dependencies between the variables. For two variables it is not that hard:

1. $x>y$
2. $x<y$
3. $x=y$

I guess there are no other results in that case, but with three variables the party begins. Sometimes it is clear:

1. $x=y=z$

..

but sometimes I need to check the relation between $x$ and $z$..

14. $x > y; \quad y < z; \quad x~ \{>, =,  <\} ~z$.

Can someone tell me which mathematics function can I use to figure out how many different results I can get?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "different results" ? Do you mean, in how many ways you can compare $n$ variables, having 3 comparisons? Essentially, when you write
$$
x=y=z 
$$
it really means
$$
x=y \qquad \text{and}\qquad y= z
$$
So it's not very clear if these can be counted as separate results.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the part "sometimes I need to check the relation between x and z" and the next line. What is "x > | = | < z" ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @MattiP., by different results I mean all posibilities that can happen in comparison between these three variables. 
I have changed already my note, this $$x > y; y < z; x { >,=,<} z.$$ means that even if we know that $x$ is greater than $y$ and $y$ is smaller than $z$, still we need to take care of the relation between $x$ and $z$ because these values might be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want all the cases that may hold for $n$ variables. Let those variables be $x_1,\cdots , x_n$. For the case $n=3$ we have $$x=y=z\\x=y<z\\x=y>z\\x<y=z\\x<y<z\\x<y>z\\x>y<z\\x>y>z\\x>y=z$$generally$$x_1\square x_2\square\cdots \square x_{n-1}\square x_n$$where the $\square$s can be filled with $\{>,=,<\}$; leading to a total of **$3^{n-1}$ distinct cases**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! But in case: $$ x < y > z$$ we still don't know the relation between x and z, am I right? Might be that: $$ x > z$$ $$x=z$$ $$x < z$$.

Comment: Your welcome. Yes and if you are looking for relations containing full information about 3 variables, the total number of cases becomes $13$. Generalizing it to $n$ variables should be cumbersome.

Comment: it looks like I have indeed 13 different results. Looks like I catch all of them. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck!!